# Cursor jumps frequently to top left

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I have a laptop with **Ubuntu 16.04 dual booted with with Windows 10**.Very frequently the **cursor jumps to the top left of the screen**.During this time touchpad function of **tap to click and right click also stops functioning** but touchpad buttons do work.After sometime it returns normal to be repeated again.Also **when pressing the up arrow** **key in keyboard** the issue stops before returning again.

The issue seems to occur very frequently in Ubuntu than in Win10.In windows the issue comes after a long usage(after about 30 minutes and that too goes away after sometime).In ubuntu it starts right after startup.Meanwhile recently i observed that sometimes during booting process in Ubuntu,the boot splash screen(the one with ubuntu logo) flickers randomly for some time before entering the lock screen..

- Computer-HP Pavilion
- OS Type-64 bit
- Touchpad-Synaptic Touchpad

Please help me..Too difficult to even type this.Has to press up arrow each time to type..

Answer (score 1):

If it happens in both windows & linux on the same hardware, then try a "hardware test" (provided by the hardware manufacturer, usually run from windows).

And/or there's some "usability" setting, configured to a slightly different threshold between the two OS, e.g., "disable touchpad while typing" (just guessing), perhaps enabled Windows & disabled in linux. Or maybe one of these settings are configured to a different sensitivity level. (All this assumes it's *not* a hardware problem, but rather how your hands may be triggering the mouse to jump to the corner of the screen)

Also, fwiw, 16.04 is pretty old (released 04/2016); perhaps try 17.10 (released 10/2017) and see if that improves the situation. You can try a newer Ubuntu directly via a bootable USB, rather than re-installing. (Maybe try kubuntu, too, trying to tweak keyboard/mouse/touchpad settings.)

Comment: Thank you..I did a windows reset and it cleared the issue